# Leader Election Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, cluster-computing, master-slave

I am exploring various architectures in cluster computing. Some of the popular ones are:

1. Master-Slave.
2. RPC
3. ...

In Master-slave, the normal way is to set one machine as master & a bunch of machines as slaves controlled by master. One particular algo here got me interested. It's called [**Leader-Election Algo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election) which has a certain randomness in selecting which of the machines will become master.

My question is - Why would anyone want to elect a master machine this way? What advantages does this approach have compared to manually selecting a machine as master?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some advantages with this algorithms:

1. Selection of node as leader will be
   done dynamically so for example you
   can select node with highest
   performance, and arrival of new
   nodes may be makes better choice.
2. Another good approach by dynamically
   selecting leader is, if one of a
   nodes have major fault (for example
   PC is shutting down) you have other
   choices and there is no need to
   manually change the leader.
3. if you manually select node should
   manually configure all other nodes
   to use this node, and also set their
   time manually, ... but this
   algorithms will help you to handle
   timing issues.
4. for example (not very relevant) why
   in most cases using DHCP? too many
   configs will be handeled by this
   algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Main idea of using such algorithms is to get rid of additional configuration, add some kind of flexibility, and stability of the whole system. But usually (in HPC/MPI applications) master node is selected manually.

Suppose your master selection algorithms is quite easy - get the list of available systems and select the one with the highest IP address. In this case you can easily start a new process on any of your nodes and it will automatically find the master node.

One nice example of such ideas is the WCCP  protocol "designated proxy" selection algorithm where the number of proxies could be flexible and master node is selected in the runtime.

Comment: I know it's an old answer but I had to correct you in case some others are reading. The main idea between a leader election algorithm is to have a leader _in a dynamic system_ which means you must have an algorithm that selects it (thus leader election algorithms - there are alot of them- ). In MPI, the master is selected manually _only to test_ the main algorithm and not in the final code.

Answer (score 2):

Considering a network of nodes, where it is vital to have one leader node at all times. If the current leader dies, then the network some how has to choose another leader. Given this scenario and requirement there are two possible ways to do it.

1. The central system approach, where there is a central node
   deciding who will be the leader. If
   the current leader dies, then this
   central node will decide on who
   should take over the leader role.
   But this is single point of failure,
   that is the central node who is
   responsible for deciding the leader,
   goes down then there is no one there to select leaders if the current leader dies.
2. Where as in the same scenario we can
   use distributed leader selection, as
   in all the nodes come to a consensus
   who the leader should be. So we do not need to have a central node who decides on who the leader should be, hence eliminating the single point of failure. When the leader node dies, then there will be a way to detect node failure, and then every node will start a distributed leader selection algorithm, and mutually come to a consensus of electing a leader.

So, in short when you have a system which has no central control, probably because the system is meant to be scalable without having single point of failure, in those systems to take choose some node, leader elections algorithms are used.